# how to retrieve the values from a list of hashes in java

Tags: java, list, hash, hashmap, key

hi i am very new to java.
In my code one of my method does this

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> hashes = db.getValue("LoginUser");
```

which returns a list of hashes

**[{"email":"xxx","password":"*****"}]**

the main thing i want to know is how to use the key value from this hash.

the way i followed to get the value of the key email is as such:

```
hashes.get(0).get("email")
```

and to get the value of key password is as such:

`hashes.get(0).get("password")`.

can we do this in some better way instead of hardcoding with index 0 here.
Could any one please suggest me with the code.

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense.  You're saying that you have an array of hashes, but don't want to access a specific element of the array.  How else will you get your hash, then?

Answer (score 1):

Use `POJO` instead of using `HashMap<String, String>`

```
class UserDetails{
     String email;
     String password;
     //Setters and Getters
}

List<UserDetails> hashes = db.getValue("LoginUser");

UserDetails userDetails = hashes.get(0);

userDetails.getEmail();
userDetails.getPassword();
```